# PowerPoint 2010 is contacting who?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I just upgraded to PowerPoint 2010, and have noticed that when I copy an image (right-click) from Google Chrome and try to paste it into a PPT, there is a short delay and the PowerPoint status bar reads something like: *contacting the server* before the image is pasted.

Who is PowerPoint contacting? Is this a new feature? I never noticed any such behavior in 2007...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you drag an image from a web browser to another application the receiving application receives a URL pointing to the image, which it must then download.  Drag the image to your desktop first, and then drag it from there to the app and the image will be copied from local storage and web server won't need to be contacted.

Comment: very interesting! So when I "copy" to my clipboard from a browser I'm not actually copying the image, I'm actually copying the image URL only?